# Understanding joining of three tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join

The database schema below represents a fictional shows database called `hbtn_0d_tvshows` tables.

| tv_shows |
| --- |
| id |
| title |

| tv_genres |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| tv_show_genres |
| --- |
| id |
| show_id |
| genre_id |

The `tv_show_genres` is a pivot table that links tv_shows and tv_genres tables. Now I have been given a task to retrieve rows without the comedy genre in them. A friend came up with the below query and it works.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `title`
  FROM `tv_shows` AS t
       LEFT JOIN `tv_show_genres` AS s
       ON s.`show_id` = t.`id`

       LEFT JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
       ON g.`id` = s.`genre_id`
       WHERE t.`title` NOT IN
             (SELECT `title`
                FROM `tv_shows` AS t
                 INNER JOIN `tv_show_genres` AS s
             ON s.`show_id` = t.`id`

             INNER JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
             ON g.`id` = s.`genre_id`
             WHERE g.`name` = "Comedy")
 ORDER BY `title`;
```

My question is, why do we need the subquery when we can put a where clause like this `where g.name != "Comedy"` in the outer query. And since all tables are already loaded by the joins, the filter should work. Like below SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `title`
      FROM `tv_shows` AS t
           LEFT JOIN `tv_show_genres` AS s
           ON s.`show_id` = t.`id`

           LEFT JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
           ON g.`id` = s.`genre_id`
           WHERE g.`name` != "Comedy";
```

May be I am missing something, but this is a cause of confusion for me and a stumble in my SQL learning.

[Sample database with data](https://s3.amazonaws.com/intranet-projects-files/holbertonschool-higher-level_programming+/274/hbtn_0d_tvshows.sql)

Expected results

```sql
title
Better Call Saul
Breaking Bad
Dexter
Game of Thrones
Homeland
House
```

Comment: I'd guess readers might appreciate a few sample data (e.g. as `Create Table...` + `Insert Into ...` statement lines), and a description of the expected result, in order to illustrate what exactly "works" and "does not work" mean for you. See also https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: because you want to exclude  titles and and with your second query you would only remove rows that have not comedy in it so titles that have multiple genres would not be eliminated

Comment: @nbk my assumption of how sql joins work was that all joins are turned in to big table with rows from the selected columns across all tables. Later the where conditions will be applied to the big table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your second query, which does not provide the desired result:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `title`
FROM `tv_shows` AS t
LEFT JOIN `tv_show_genres` AS s
    ON s.`show_id` = t.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
    ON g.`id` = s.`genre_id`
WHERE g.`name` != "Comedy";
```

Firstly, don't use `"Comedy"` (double quotes) for string literals. It works (with default MySQL config) but is non-standard and should be avoided. Use `'Comedy'` (single quotes) instead.

Secondly, because your `WHERE` clause is applied to the rightmost table (`tv_genres.name`), your `LEFT` joins are implicitly changed to `INNER` joins.

As already explained by nbk in the comments, your `WHERE` clause is just including all rows where `g.name != 'Comedy'`, which is not the same as "TV shows that do not have the comedy genre".

Now, let's jump back to your first query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `title`
  FROM `tv_shows` AS t
       LEFT JOIN `tv_show_genres` AS s
       ON s.`show_id` = t.`id`

       LEFT JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
       ON g.`id` = s.`genre_id`
       WHERE t.`title` NOT IN
             (SELECT `title`
                FROM `tv_shows` AS t
                 INNER JOIN `tv_show_genres` AS s
             ON s.`show_id` = t.`id`

             INNER JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
             ON g.`id` = s.`genre_id`
             WHERE g.`name` = "Comedy"'Comedy')
 ORDER BY `title`;
```

The two `LEFT` joins in the outer query are doing nothing, so we can get rid of them. This also means `DISTINCT` is no longer needed. Instead of joining (for `` t.`title` NOT IN ``) on the `title`, we should be using the `id`, which has the added bonus of not needing to join `tv_shows` in the subquery:

```sql
SELECT `title`
FROM `tv_shows` AS t
WHERE t.`id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `show_id`
    FROM `tv_show_genres` AS s
    INNER JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
        ON g.`id` = s.`genre_id`
    WHERE g.`name` = 'Comedy'
)
 ORDER BY `title`;
```

This can be rewritten as a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`:

```sql
SELECT `title`
FROM `tv_shows` AS t
LEFT JOIN `tv_show_genres` AS s
    ON s.`show_id` = t.`id`
    AND s.`genre_id` = (SELECT id FROM `tv_genres` WHERE `name` = 'Comedy')
WHERE s.`genre_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `title`;
```

or `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tv_shows s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tv_show_genres sg
    JOIN tv_genres g ON sg.genre_id = g.id
    WHERE sg.show_id = s.id
    AND g.name = 'Comedy'
)
ORDER BY title;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y2lN98FT).

Note that I have changed the indexing of `tv_show_genres` in the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y2lN98FT). With few exceptions, pivot tables need composite indices in both directions - `PK(show_id, genre_id)` and secondary `(genre_id, show_id)`.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is the best option. There are good articles that explain why. Here an example: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: @user1191247, how does conditions on the right outer table work when used in a join of two tables like in your first solution subquery

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic Sorry, I am not sure which query you are referring to. If you run the queries with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/) you should get a better understanding of how the different queries work. Note that the `NOT IN (subquery)` and `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` result in the same execution plans, for this specific case - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XN_TVV_G). You can use [OPTIMIZER_TRACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_OPT_TRACE.html) to further explore what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

With your test data and query

```
select *
from tv_shows as s
left join tv_show_genres as sg on sg.show_id=s.id
left join tv_genres g on g.id=sg.genre_id
```

output is

| id | title | show_id | genre_id | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | House | 1 | 1 | 1 | Drama |
| 1 | House | 1 | 2 | 2 | Mystery |
| 2 | Game of Thrones | 2 | 3 | 3 | Adventure |
| 2 | Game of Thrones | 2 | 1 | 1 | Drama |
| 2 | Game of Thrones | 2 | 4 | 4 | Fantasy |
| 3 | The Big Bang Theory | 3 | 5 | 5 | Comedy |
| 4 | New Girl | 4 | 5 | 5 | Comedy |
| 5 | Silicon Valley | 5 | 5 | 5 | Comedy |
| 6 | Breaking Bad | 6 | 6 | 6 | Crime |
| 6 | Breaking Bad | 6 | 1 | 1 | Drama |
| 6 | Breaking Bad | 6 | 7 | 7 | Suspense |
| 6 | Breaking Bad | 6 | 8 | 8 | Thriller |
| 7 | Better Call Saul | null | null | null | null |
| 8 | Dexter | 8 | 6 | 6 | Crime |
| 8 | Dexter | 8 | 1 | 1 | Drama |
| 8 | Dexter | 8 | 2 | 2 | Mystery |
| 8 | Dexter | 8 | 7 | 7 | Suspense |
| 8 | Dexter | 8 | 8 | 8 | Thriller |
| 9 | Homeland | null | null | null | null |
| 10 | The Last Man on Earth | 10 | 5 | 5 | Comedy |
| 10 | The Last Man on Earth | 10 | 1 | 1 | Drama |

A) As commented by @nbk , some titles, that have multiple genres,  would not be eliminated by condition `` WHERE g.`name` != "Comedy" ``

B) If `genre_id` for some `title` is not assigned, condition `` WHERE g.`name` != "Comedy" `` is equal to condition `` WHERE g.`name` != null ``
So:
"Comedy"=null - is false
"Comedy"!=null - is false
or
g.name = null - is false
g.name != null - is false

and this condition not work as desired.

C) Your first query may be better write like this

```
SELECT title
FROM `tv_shows` AS t
WHERE id not in
    (
     SELECT show_id
     FROM `tv_show_genres` AS s
     INNER JOIN `tv_genres` AS g
           ON s.`genre_id` = g.`id`
     WHERE g.`name` = "Comedy"
   )
 ORDER BY `title`;
```

to avoid cases when there are several rows with the same `Title`
and this query has better performance.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9-BPS012)

Answer (score -1):

I prepared some example: https://dbfiddle.uk/mb1_Vlc0

I put additional column in the `tv_shows` table with name `channel`.
So, now we have two TV-shows with the same name "Funny title" for the different channels: NBC and NBC2.
And on the NBC this is Comedy, but on the NBC2 this is Detective.
Your first example excludes title "Funny title" at all, but your second query will leave this name for one of the channels.

Now you need to make desigion, if you need logic from the first of the sercond query.

Data model:

```
insert into tv_shows values
(1, 'First title', 'NBC'),
(2, 'Second title', 'SomeTVShowChannel'),
(3, 'Some title', 'NBC'),
(4, 'Funny title', 'NBC'),
(5, 'Funny title', 'NBC2');
insert into tv_genres values
(1, 'Comedy'),
(2, 'Detective');
insert into tv_show_genres values
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 2),
(3, 3, 2),
(4, 4, 1),
(5, 5, 2);
```

Screenshot from the my link just for demonstration.
[image]